# How to store images to a folder in network and reference them in views - asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, knockout.js

My application (asp.net mvc knockout) has a feature wherein Admin user can upload a .png or .jpg file and tie it to an entity.Currently all images in my application are stored under "\Images\Icons" in root application folder. But due to a policy saving images to a folder in Webserver is not permitted, so have to move them to a shared folder in the network "\XYZ.net\Shared\AppName\Images\Icons". Now when entity details are displayed on view along with images, the images are not displayed. Fiddler shows a 400 Bad request error, URL - GET `http://localhost:52624/ApplicationName/%5CXYZ.net%5CShared%5CAppName%5CImages%5CIcons%5CAbc.png HTTP/1.1`

Any tips to resolve this issue ?

---

**Old code:** In Layout.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var BASE_URL = '@Url.Content("~/")';</script>
In View:
<!-- ko if: Icon() -->
   <img data-bind="attr: {src : BASE_URL + 'Images/Icons/' + Icon()}" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

**New Code:**

```
var IMG_URL = '\\XYZ.net\\Shared\\AppName\\';
<!-- ko if: Icon() -->
    <img data-bind="attr: {src : IMG_URL + 'Images\\Icons\\' + Icon()}" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices:

- Add a virtual directory on IIS to point to the network drive.
- On the server, intercept calls to a specific route (e.g., http://www.myserver.com/images). Process the Request and push the file to the client using Response.

This is not something that can be done on the client.

Comment: Thank you, Adam.I was looking at a blog posted by [morgan on Aug 6, 2009](http://www.phpvs.net/2009/08/06/aspnet-mvc-how-to-route-to-images-or-other-file-types/). This looks like an old blog, if you are aware of any new online examples can you direct me to them.

Comment: Also will the implementation of 2nd approach to intercept call to a specific route and writing to response lead to poor user experience in terms of slowing the page load etc...

Answer (score 0):

I would add to Adam Zuckerman's answer that you have may have an issue accessing the files on localhost.  You may need to make localhost host a trusted site.

Comment: Eric, the web infrastructure team refused to make localhost a trusted site for reasons best known to them. Thank you, for help.